# Laravel where to store ajax methods

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm having a RESTful Resource Controller with basic CRUD functionality. My pages contain a lot of ajax requests, which make a simple controller extend over 500 lines of code, make it very unclear, complex and confusing (especially with working in a team).

How and where should I declare the ajax methods for my controller? I tried messing with php's `include_once` and put it in a seperated file in a folder named AJAX but this doesn't seem to me to be the right option. What is adviced for this situation?

Answer (score -1):

if you are working on a fairly big project its better to extend it with concepts behind the domain model in domain driven design, such as services and repositories.
you can read more about it in [Domain Model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html)

or for simplicity you can put your ajax.js in public folder and call it with asset() laravel built-in function.